# Filter values to include features within a specific max/min range

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query

I have a table of values that have a MIN and MAX integer value, i.e.

[image]

I would like to select all values that range from `Age_MIN >= 105 to Age_MAX <= 110`.  There are features in the table that would fall into that range, but I'm not sure how to query them.

When I do a definition query with Age_MIN >= 105 to Age_MAX <= 110 I get this result:

[image]

As a visual representation of what I would like to do, please see below image:
[image]

Here, the features (horizontal bars) in blue would be selected, and the yellow bars would be unselected as they don't fall within the range of 100 to 110.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can see nothing in 2nd column <=65. No wonder selection is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I edited above so that it makes more sense now.

Comment: If you have an idea of how to select features as shown in the bar graph above I would love to hear it!

Comment: `(AgeMin <= 110) and (AgeMax >= 100)`

Comment: Same, no features selected.  I know this sounds like a _very simple task_, and I've been telling myself the same thing, but I really don't know how to do this......

Comment: The fields are both long integers

Comment: Correct answer given by @BERA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the age ranges that in some way overlap 100-110 the query should be:

```
(AgeMin <= 110) AND (AgeMax >=100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Selection >> Select by attribute**

```
"Age_MIN" >= 60 AND "Age_MAX" <= 110
```

**Update:**
From your field values in the picture attached in your question and as FelixIP mentioned that there are no values <=65 so in this case you will get no records.

Comment: I tried that before as it seemed the most logical thing to do - that query returns no values

Comment: @FrancisMacDonald Can you add a screenshot of a sample from your table to see the data how it looks like

Comment: @FrancisMacDonald just press edit then press on the image icon

Comment: got it, posted above

Comment: ok sorry, lets make it Age_MIN >= 105, and Age_MAX <= 110.  There are values that fall within the range in the table.  How would I select those?

Comment: Again, there are no values > 105 in the (Age_Min). The expression that I wrote in my answer is the same, you can just change the values to get the result.

Comment: Edited again with visual representation to make sure the issue is clear.  I tried the query and it returned no results.

Comment: Yes exactly, but how do I structure this so that I get results as in the figure with the bar graph above?